# logic of point of sale?

Tags: c#, sql, identity, point-of-sale

my tables ...

```
create table sale
(
idsale int primary key identity,
idclient int,
user1 varchar(50),
fecha datetime
)

create table listofsale
(
idsale int,
idproduct int,
amount int,
priceunit float,
subtotal
)
```

when the sale is finished i am going to insert all
i refer i am going to insert the information of

```
table sale
```

and `listofsale`
then i do the insert, but how do i get the same idsale for the list?
another idea i had is my idsale was `varchar (10)`
and i do a random of letters and number in c# and i am going to have it
in a textbox, so i can save it, in the same time,

or, what another form can i do it?
what is the best way for do it?

-- added
{
I always have had a button for "insert" the sale and get the id, 
and after of do it you can add the list..
but i know it is not the right form..
sometime you have sales without list (if you dont added none product , and close the application and open it again)
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sort of having a hard time understanding what the problem is. Reading through, it seems to me that you don't necessarily have a problem generating sale ids, but rather, in maintaining one sale list for a client across sessions/computers/instances/etc.?

Assumptions: 
1) that a particular client can only have one sale list at a time, and 
2) that your column "idclient" is the ID of the client to whom that sale list belongs.

Solution: 
Instead of looking for a sale, look for the idclient, in table sale, of the client in question. If that comes back with nothing, create a new sale for that client, if it does come back with a sale, use that saleid. Do this whenever you need that saleid.

Better Solution:
Above solution only allows you to ever have one sale, and thus sale list, per client. If you want any number of past, completed sales, but only one current, open one, do this:

Add an "isSaleCompleted" boolean column to table sale. Set that to true only when a sale is completed and done. 
Then, in the same client sale search as above, also check that isSaleCompleted is false.

So, the client sale search stored procedure would look like so:

```
CREATE Procedure ClientSaleSearch
(
    @clientid int
)
SELECT saleid
From Sale
WHERE id=@userid AND isSaleCompleted = '0'
```

Answer (score 4):

You have several options.  (more info here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

1. use SCOPE_IDENTITY() which returns the last identity value created in the current session and is limited to current scope as well.  This gets around issues with @@IDENTITY.
2. Have the INSERT statement give you the inserted ID via the OUTPUT clause ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx )
3. Instead of using an Int as your key, use a uniqueidentifier (GUID).  **Benefit**: You could create the id client side and submit it to the server.  **Downside**: it will cause hell for your indexes.

If it was up to me and I wanted to be 100% certain of the ID value I was getting back, then I'd use option #2 above.

Answer (score 1):

When you do **INSERT INTO sale ....**
The SQL **@@IDENTITY** variable will contain the last generated value of the **idsale**.
You can use this value to insert desired **idsale** to your **listofsale** table.

If you need more information you can find it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx

Comment: i know! but what happens if you do it since 2 computer, in the same time? i dont want to have this problem.. @Sasha

Comment: If you do insert on 2 different clients @@IDENTITY will have a different value for each of it since you will have 1 inserts for each client. @@IDENTITY has SQL session scope. Means it is not shared between SQL sessions.

Comment: ok you have 2 diferents values, but what happens when i do (select max(idsale) from sale) for added it to my table listofsale, then it is going to get the last!, and in the computer1, and in the computer2, is going to add to the listofsale with idsale with the lastnumber, this is going to be a problem!

Comment: @Sasha: Not necessarily.  If there are triggers involved the @@identity could reference some other identity value that has nothing to do with what the OP is after.

Comment: @angel: you can't trust "select max(idsale) ..."  If there were multiple inserts that occurred near simultaneously then it doesn't work.

Comment: @Chris i know, for that i want a solution, do you believe a must to do a randam string before insert it? because this string is goig to be my idsale? then it would be varchar

Comment: @angel: No, that introduces other problems such as collision potential.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you should make primary keys (like idsale) as varchar because it slows down searching and retrieving data. Try to make idsale as autonumber, and after inserting data in sale table get the id of last-inserted identity value and use it for inserting in listofsale.

When working on my point of sale ([TradeMeters](http://www.TradeMeters.com/)) I designed table like this:

```
SaleItems
{
    transaction_id int,
    product_id int,
    quantity float,
    unit_price float,
    discount float
}
```

Note subtotal is not required because you can calculate subtotal from amount and priceunit.

```
Subtotal = priceunit x amount
```